# Can a player use feats from a campaign setting book that is not being used for the game

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, eberron, dark-sun

Should a player identify a feat from an Eberron Campaign book while playing Dark Sun, and that feat is not environment - campaign race - or setting specific, can the player import the feat and use it for their Dark Sun campaign character?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**It depends on your GM, but if you're playing in a book-specific setting, probably not**

Which books allowed in the game are strictly a DM's call. While many GMs play with "all books allowed" there are a number that choose to restrict books. One of the more common restrictions are on setting specific material, though it is fairly trivial to file off serial-numbers.

Beyond GM fiat and the restrictions of setting (dragonmark feats are a little hard to port to Dark Sun), there are no real restrictions on usable feats.

Comment: Seconded ... it's all down to the DM

Answer (score 2):

As a GM, I'd say absolutely not unless I feel that it's a valid supplement. If it's totally fair, I'd say there's not necessarily harm in it, but I'd still not use it except under a handful of conditions just to prevent confusion and prevent book juggling.

Answer (score 2):

It's completely GM dependent. I usually allow it when it's not setting specific, but almost never when it is.
In any case, consult with your DM, since nothing we say here counts.